# How to translate wordpress widget name?

Tags: wordpress, widget, translate

I have correctly created a custom widget, evreything is translating well with a correct .po file, except the title.

Here is my code :

```
$concert_widget_name = __('Tour Dates', 'concerts');
wp_register_sidebar_widget (
    'tourdates',                 // your unique widget id
    $concert_widget_name,         // widget name
    'tourdates_widget_display',  // callback function to display widget
    array(                       // options
        'description' => 'Displaying upcoming tour dates'
    )
);
```

Is there an error ? An other way to translate the widget name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually register my widgets using the [register_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) function. In the constructor of the widget class I place the following code:

```
class TourDates extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $options = array('classname' => 'tour-dates', 'description' => __('Display upcoming tour dates'));
        parent::__construct('tour_dates', __('Tour Dates'), $options);
    }
}
```

You can also check out the [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) on the WordPress Codex site. Hopefully this helps you in creating your custom widget.

Also what I usually do is merge my translations with the default ones loaded from WordPress, like so:

```
function loadTextDomain() {
    $locale = get_locale();
    $languageDir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/languages';

    $domain = 'default';
    $mofile = $languageDir . '/theme.' . $locale . '.mo';

    global $l10n;
    $mo = new MO();
    if (!$mo->import_from_file($mofile)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($l10n[$domain]) && !empty($l10n[$domain]->entries)) {
        $l10n[$domain]->merge_with($mo);
    } else {
        $l10n[$domain] = $mo;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'loadTextDomain');
```

This code looks similar to the `load_textdomain` function from WordPress but it avoids all the filters that do exist in the original function, which helps in avoiding any WordPress hook from altering your `$domain` and `$mofile` variables.

But I will leave that up to you. Maybe the `load_textdomain()` function from WordPress will work just as fine, but in case it doesn't this function should do the trick.

Now if your using the `loadTextDomain()` function I pasted above you can just place a `languages` folder in the same folder as your `functions.php` resides, in that new folder you could place `theme.nl_NL.mo` or `theme.de_DE.mo` files depending on the language your using. This should allow translation of your website and also the admin area.